# Issue when accessing a deployed app on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed a MERN app on minikube and i was unable to access it thourgh NODE_PORT and NODE_IP although i configured correctly the nodeport service for the frontend and the clusterip service for(backend node js app & mongo db).
Also i was sure that the service selected the correct pod based on the labels , but unfortunatly i cannot see the app on the browser it take time for loading and eventually it times out !
Note :

- The react app is running on port 8080.
- The backend app is running on port 3000.
- I created the service with nodeport type and used tagret port as the same container port .
  Thanks for the help !

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: frontend
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bookstore-frontend-pod
          image: achref2h/bookstore-frontend:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: frontend-svc
  name: frontend-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: frontend-pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bookstore-backend-pod
          image: achref2h/bookstore-backend:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: backend-svc
  name: backend-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend-pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: One obvious thing here is that the `backend-svc` isn't visible outside the cluster.  If the frontend service proxies to it then that's fine, but if the browser application needs to directly connect to the backend, the backend needs to also be a NodePort or LoadBalancer Service, or to have an Ingress in front of it.

Comment: But the connection between containers is handled by k8s and when I inspect the logs I don't see any err. I think exposing only the frontend service is correct even the firewall is disabled when I checked it ! and I run the same architecture on docker compose and it went well I think these two methods are similar but I don't know why it didn't work in the k8s environment